# PHP: Expose 'get' and 'set' for object with nested associative arrays

Tags: php, arrays, class, associative-array

I have a class which stores values with a multi-level associative array:

I need to add a way to access and modify nested values. Here is a working solution for my problem, but **it is rather slow**. Is there **a better way of doing this**?

Note: The use of get / set functions is not mandatory, but there needs to be an efficient way to define a default value.

```
class Demo {
    protected $_values = array();

    function __construct(array $values) {
        $this->_values = $values;
    }

    public function get($name, $default = null) {
        $token = strtok($name, '.#');
        $node = $this->_values;
        while ($token !== false) {
            if (!isset($node[$token]))
                return $default;
            $node = $node[$token];
            $token = strtok('.#');
        }
        return $node;
    }

    public function set($name, $value) {
        $next_token = strtok($name, '.#');
        $node = &$this->_values;

        while ($next_token !== false) {
            $token = $next_token;
            $next_token = strtok('.#');

            if ($next_token === false) {
                $node[ $token ] = $value;
                break;
            }
            else if (!isset($node[ $token ]))
                $node[ $token ] = array();

            $node = &$node[ $token ];
        }

        unset($node);
    }

}
```

Which would be used as follows:

```
$test = new Demo(array(
    'simple'  => 27,
    'general' => array(
        0 => array(
            'something'    => 'Hello World!',
            'message'      => 'Another message',
            'special'      => array(
                'number'       => 27
            )
        ),
        1 => array(
            'something'    => 'Hello World! #2',
            'message'      => 'Another message #2'
        ),
    )
));

$simple = $test->get('simple'); // === 27

$general_0_something = $test->get('general#0.something'); // === 'Hello World!'

$general_0_special_number = $test->get('general#0.special.number'); === 27
```

Note: 'general.0.something' is the same as 'general#0.something', the alternative punctuation is for the purpose of clarity.

Comment: Why do you save and get the data in different formats?

Comment: @powtac I am not sure that I understand your question. If you are referring to the way in which I have initialised the demo then the answer is, it is just for the demo. The actual way in which the array of values comes to be is rather complex. I just wanted to provide a clean and uncluttered question.

Comment: You want to receive 'Hello World!'? Or what should be the result?

Comment: You save it as array, but you request the data with an string as parameter.

Comment: Please provide more sample data. The one example is not enough or does not make sense.

Comment: Normally you don't set data like this in an constructor, you would have a extra method for this.

Comment: @powtac the data is stored in a hierarchical fashion and it has to be possible to access the leaf nodes / values. So $value === 'Hello World!' at the end of the above demo.

Comment: @powtac the data is not provided in the constructor in actual implementation, it is generated by a series of complex operations within the object. It is just for demonstration. I just need to optimize the 'get' function

Comment: No prob, but please add an additional example of $values.

Comment: @powtac I have added some more examples.

Comment: @Lea Hayes: I suspect you might be looking for the same functionality as provided by the `Zend_Dom_Query` component of Zend Framework. You might consider having a look at it: http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.dom.query.html

Comment: @Lea Hayes: uh, no. I guess I was wrong now that I look at your additional examples.

Comment: @Lea Hayes: And what's wrong with your current method of doing it? It seems OK, especially if you want a nice getter syntax.

Comment: What are the rules to split your request keys? Once a . is the separator once a #... Is this the logic?

Comment: @powtac The # simply denotes a numerically indexed value, it is primarily syntax candy.  i.e.   shopping-list.item#24.ingredient#2.name

Comment: @powtac but shopping-list.item.24.ingredient.2.name  would achieve the same output

Comment: @Karol Piczak it does work, but it is just so incredibly slow average lookup is 0.0033919811 ms with nice method (only takes 0 .0008251667 ms with an `if (isset(` and normal array access)

Comment: @Lea Hayes: I've had an attempt at the getter by using `preg_split` in stead of `strtok`, but it was twice as slow. So I think your solution is pretty fast as it is. I'd be surprised to see a faster solution.

Comment: @fireeyedboy I think that you are probably right, thank you very much for trying, and thanks to everybody who has contributed. Very much appreciated.

Comment: @fireeyedboy: I concur. I had a shot with direct array access with `eval()`. And *that* is slow. :-) @Lea Hayes: There's not much space left for optimization here if you want to sustain your requirements. If performance is such an issue, why not stay with proven `isset(...) ? ... : 'default'` constructs?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, the question was interesting enough that I couldn't resist tinkering a bit more. :-)

So, here are my conclusions. **Your implementation** is probably the most **straightforward and clear**. And it's working, so I wouldn't really bother about searching for another solution. In fact, how much calls are you gonna get in the end? Is the difference in performance worth the trouble (I mean between "*super ultra blazingly fast*" and "*almost half as fast*")?

Put aside though, **if performance is really an issue** (getting thousands of calls), then there's a way to reduce the execution time if you repetitively lookup the array.

In your version the greatest burden falls on *string operations* in your `get` function. Everything that touches *string manipulation* is doomed to fail in this context. And that was indeed the case with all my initial attempts at solving this problem.

It's hard not to touch *strings* if we want such a syntax, but we can at least **limit how much string operations we do**.

If you create a **hash map** (hash table) so that you can **flatten your multidimensional array** to a one level deep structure, then most of the computations done are a one time expense. It pays off, because this way you can almost directly lookup your values by the *string* provided in your `get` call.

I've come up with something roughly like this:

```
<?php

class Demo {
    protected $_values = array();
    protected $_valuesByHash = array();

    function createHashMap(&$array, $path = null) {
        foreach ($array as $key => &$value) {
            if (is_array($value)) {
                $this->createHashMap($value, $path.$key.'.');
            } else {
                $this->_valuesByHash[$path.$key] =& $value;
            }
        }
    }

    function __construct(array $values) {
        $this->_values = $values;
        $this->createHashMap($this->_values);

        // Check that references indeed work
        // $this->_values['general'][0]['special']['number'] = 28;
        // print_r($this->_values);
        // print_r($this->_valuesByHash);
        // $this->_valuesByHash['general.0.special.number'] = 29;
        // print_r($this->_values);
        // print_r($this->_valuesByHash);
    }

    public function get($hash, $default = null) {
        return isset($this->_valuesByHash[$hash]) ? $this->_valuesByHash[$hash] : $default;
    }
}


$test = new Demo(array(
    'simple'  => 27,
    'general' => array(
        '0' => array(
            'something'    => 'Hello World!',
            'message'      => 'Another message',
            'special'      => array(
                'number'       => 27
            )
        ),
        '1' => array(
            'something'    => 'Hello World! #2',
            'message'      => 'Another message #2'
        ),
    )
));

$start = microtime(true);

for ($i = 0; $i < 10000; ++$i) {
    $simple = $test->get('simple', 'default');
    $general_0_something = $test->get('general.0.something', 'default');
    $general_0_special_number = $test->get('general.0.special.number', 'default');
}

$stop = microtime(true);

echo $stop-$start;

?>
```

The *setter* is not yet implemented, and you would have to modify it for alternative syntax (`#` separator), but I think it conveys the idea.

At least on my testbed it takes **half the time** to execute this compared to the original implementation. Still **raw array access is faster**, but the difference in my case is around 30-40%. At the moment that was the best I could achieve. I hope that your actual case is not big enough that I've hit some memory constraints on the way. :-)

Comment: super stuff!! Thank you so much for persevering with this!

Comment: +1 Cool, totally different approach and goal than mine, but more in line with the OP's reasoning.

Answer (score 3):

Ok, my first approached missed the goal I was aiming for. Here is the solution to using native PHP array syntax (at least for access) and still being able to set a default value.

Update: Added missing functionality for get/set and on the fly converting.

By the way, this is *not* an approach to take if you are optimizing for performance. This is perhaps 20 times slower than regular array access.

```
class Demo extends ArrayObject {
    protected $_default;
    public function __construct($array,$default = null) {
        parent::__construct($array);
        $this->_default = $default;
    }
    public function  offsetGet($index) {
        if (!parent::offsetExists($index)) return $this->_default;
        $ret = parent::offsetGet($index);
        if ($ret && is_array($ret)) {
            parent::offsetSet($index, $this->newObject($ret));
            return parent::offsetGet($index);
        }
        return $ret;
    }
    protected function newObject(array $array=null) {
        return new self($array,$this->_default);
    }
}
```

Init

```
$test = new Demo(array(
    'general' => array(
        0 => array(
            'something'    => 'Hello World!'
        )
    )
),'Default Value');
```

Result

```
$something = $test['general'][0]['something']; // 'Hello World!'
$notfound = $test['general'][0]['notfound']; // 'Default Value'
```

Comment: @Peter: no offense, but this is 'pretty' fugly. ;)

Comment: None taken, I know that, this was sort of a failed attempt of making it 'pretty'.

Comment: @Peter: I see what you tried to do though, especially with the `offsetGet` part. That would have been my path of reasoning as well probably. Only to end up with pretty much the same as with what you ended up with. :)

Comment: @Peter: that is very nice actually! Problem is; I think OP wants to be able to set a default value with the getter, in stead of a 'global' default value. Now, your first attempt actually had this, but I think it kind of defeats the purpose, as OP wanted to circumvent doing `$value = isset( $test['general'][0]['notfound'] ) ? $test['general'][0]['notfound'] : 'some default value';` Which is not much different then `$test->setDefault( 'some default value' ); $value = $test['general'][0]['notfound'];`. Nonetheless, this is a decent way to access multidimensional elements in an `ArrayObject`!

Comment: So just for that, I am gonna upvote this, with the note that it is probably not exactly what OP was looking for. But of course OP is the only one to be the judge of that. :)

Comment: Yes, you're right about that, also I'm not sure that the speed of this is right.

Comment: @Peter Lindqvist thanks, like @fireeyedboy says, it is a very nice way to access values from an object. But unfortunately it lacks easily allowing a default value to be provided. Thank you for your efforts, they are very much appreciated.

Comment: @Lea Hayes, np, it was a fun experiment!

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for something like that? Essentially the `get()` method uses references to descend into the `$values` array and breaks out of the method if a requirement could not be met.

```
class Demo {
    protected $_values = array();

    public function __construct(array $values) {
        $this->_values = $values;
    }

    public function get($name, $default = null) {
        $parts  = preg_split('/[#.]/', $name);
        if (!is_array($parts) || empty($parts)) {
            return null;
        }

        $value  = &$this->_values;
        foreach ($parts as $p) {
            if (array_key_exists($p, $value)) {
                $value  = &$value[$p];
            } else {
                return null;
            }
        }

        return $value;
    }

    /**
     * setter missing
     */
}

$test = new Demo(array(
    'simple'  => 2,
    'general' => array(
        0 => array(
                'something'    => 'Hello World!',
                'message'      => 'Another message',
                'special'      => array(
                    'number'       => 4
                )
            ),
        1 => array(
                'something'    => 'Hello World! #2',
                'message'      => 'Another message #2'
            )
    )
));

$v = $test->get('simple'); 
var_dump($v);

$v = $test->get('general'); 
var_dump($v);

$v = $test->get('general.0'); 
var_dump($v);

$v = $test->get('general#0'); 
var_dump($v);

$v = $test->get('general.0.something'); 
var_dump($v);

$v = $test->get('general#0.something'); 
var_dump($v);

$v = $test->get('general.0.message'); 
var_dump($v);

$v = $test->get('general#0.message'); 
var_dump($v);

$v = $test->get('general.0.special'); 
var_dump($v);

$v = $test->get('general#0.special'); 
var_dump($v);

$v = $test->get('general.0.special.number'); 
var_dump($v);

$v = $test->get('general#0.special.number'); 
var_dump($v);

$v = $test->get('general.1'); 
var_dump($v);

$v = $test->get('general#1'); 
var_dump($v);

$v = $test->get('general.1.something'); 
var_dump($v);

$v = $test->get('general#1.something'); 
var_dump($v);

$v = $test->get('general.1.message'); 
var_dump($v);

$v = $test->get('general#1.message'); 
var_dump($v);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how multidimensional array work in general in PHP:

```
$data = array(
    'general' => array(
         0 => array(
             'something'    => 'Hello World!'
         )
    )
);
```

To receive `Hello World`:

```
echo $data['general'][0]['something'];
```

Comment: Ideally this needs to go through a getter method so that a default can be added. Otherwise there are countless isset's